# Processor support on Intel S4600LH2/S4600LT2 Family

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

I'm looking into getting one of these boards, and they say that they're compatible with the Xeon e5 family. Is it possible to use Intel i series processors on them? I have a lot of i3 chips laying around, and I'd hate to not be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

This motherboard family is a server grade motherboard and supports only Xeon Processor Family. i3 intel processor in not a server grade processor + i-Series processors cannot support multi-CPU motherboards. So answer is no, you cannot use i3 processors with this MB. There are many other things like when you put i3 processor , the motherboard it is on doesn't expect server grade high reliable memory chips. 
Hope this helps.